# Combinatorics - Sorting objects into specific sets with no empty set using a generating function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can you sort 90 people in 3 different rooms with no room being empty?

With no restrictions sorting 90 people in 3 rooms would be 3^90. When it comes to no room empty, I start with (x+x^2/2!+...)^3 and get lost.

Comment: sorting only by number of occupants of each room, or also by their identity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use an inclusion-exclusion argument. There are, as you say, $3^{90}$ unrestricted distributions; from that you want to subtract the distributions that leave at least one room empty. For each of the $3$ rooms there are $2^{90}$ distributions leaving that room empty, so to a first approximation there are $3\cdot 2^{90}$ distributions that leave at least one room empty. However, this counts every distribution that leaves two rooms empty twice, once for each of the two empty rooms. Plainly there are $3$ such distributions: if two rooms are empty, all $90$ people are in one of the $3$ rooms. Thus, there are really only $3\cdot 2^{90}-3$ distributions that leave at least one room empty, and the final answer is therefore $3^{90}-3\cdot 2^{90}+3$.